# Stop password prompt on MAMP startup

Tags: apache, macos, localhost, mamp

I develop using MAMP pro on my Mac. When I start MAMP it prompts me for a password if I use port 80. If I use a higher port it doesn't prompt me, but I have to append the port number in the URL ( eg dev.local:8888 ).
Does anyone know how to make it not prompt for password when using standard ports?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a living-e rep they are considering adding an option to store the password in the keychain:

http://forum.webedition.de/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5517&p=12019

Update: I pestered Living-e support and got them to add it as a feature request to their bug tracker. The link is here: http://qa.living-e.de/tracker/view.php?id=3648 (requires registration) if you want to follow it.

Another update: Still following this issue. Looks like living-e moved their bug tracker, the new link to this issue is:

http://bugs.mamp.info/view.php?id=3652

It's in German but the Google translation is:

> When will start and stop the server in
> each case the admin password is
> required if port is used as low-1024th
> If we could get the password from the
> OS X Keychain / keyring, allowed
> themselves to avoid annoying popup
> ads.

Or a German speaker's translation is:

> When the Server starts/stops it will ask for the admin password each time.
> If it could get the password from OS X Keychain / Keyring, the annoying popup could be avoided.

Comment: I really wish they fixed this issue, its beyond annoying

Comment: Thanks, doesn’t look like its going to happen though, that was a while ago…

Answer (score 14):

I've put together an app that allows you to start/stop MAMP's Apache and MySQL without the password request, even on port 80. It stores the password in Keychain, so you only need to enter it once. It has a nice icon too!

Download: http://www.46palermo.com/blog/run-mamp-without-password-easy-way/

Comment: except that a sheduled shutdown still is blocked by MAMP.

Comment: still works with MAMP 3.0.7.3 and OS 10.10 (Yosemite), love it

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work for me on OS 10.10.3 and MAMP 3.0 :(

Answer (score 4):

As found on [Macworld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100421070605258) and already mentioned by Tom in the other answer there is a way with applescript! Downside is you have to save your user credentials in plain text.

1. Open AppleScript Editor
2. Enter the following code replacing `YOURPASSWORD` and `YOURUSERNAME` with your user credentials
3. Save it as application. You might tick `run-only` to prevent other users from reading the plain text as a small security measure

> ```
> do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh &" password "YOURPASSWORD" user name "YOURUSERNAME" with administrator privileges
> do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh > /dev/null 2>&1"
> ```

There might be an issue with the correct file path as MAMP apparently changed `startmySQL.sh` to `startMysql.sh` in some version, so double check if it's not working!

You can put the new application in the Login Items (System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items), so the Apache server and MySQL start automatically without even showing up the MAMP-App at startup (silent start).

Comment: not working for me on El Capitan v10.11.2 and MAMP v4.0.6

Answer (score 2):

In response to the commands that were posted:

1) Run MAMP on port > 1024

Running all of the servers on MAMP (nginx, apache, mysql) with port ranges above 1024 allows the Mac OS X account you logged in with to launch the services, so you will not be asked for a password in this instance. Any server that runs below port 1024 requires root privileges when being executed.

2) chmod -R a+w /tmp

This command would recursively go through all files and sub folders in /tmp and make them writable for the current user.  When MAMP launches, servers create temporary files in this directory.

Also if you decide you want to run the servers below port 1024 and want a solution with applescript that does not store the password in plain text then see this link [applescript password with keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599727/5626384)

Answer (score 1):

I'm now using [these two applescripts](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?t=634) to start/stop MAMP, you can save startup script is a login item so it's always up when I boot. It does mean storing your password in plain text, as Im the only one using this machine I can live with it, better than typing in my password at least three times a day.

Answer (score 1):

I bind apache to port 8080 and then use port forwarding from 80 to 8080

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to any 80 in
```

Works for me, but I'm working on making the above script permanent. So far, nothing I've tried sticks, so I just run the command above in terminal after restarting. But you can then freely start and stop MAMP without a password and use a URL without :8080 or :8888.

Answer (score 0):

Its a security issue, and MacOS with its UNIX heritage like security (=Good Thing). That's why MacOS asks for passwords all the time. Not much you can do about it as far as I know.

Comment: Its actually extremely easy to call the Keychain and store this password for use. OS X asks you to type in the password again anytime the applications binary contents have changed. Theres nothing we as USERS can do about it, but the developers of Mamp pro can easily implement this as a feature. Ive written this into about 4 applications myself.

Answer (score 0):

1) Run MAMP on port > 1024

2) chmod -R a+w /tmp

Comment: I would love an explanation of what is going on here and why this works, I'm a bit weary of side effects and it's not clear if this is two solutions or two steps.

Comment: For this answer to be of use to a wide audience, I'd suggest adding some explanation as to what these two steps are doing.