# Can I stop MAMP forcing me to type in password whenever I log in?

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, mamp, daemon

I've used MAMP for two years and am always upset with it forcing me to type in password every time I restart my Macintosh and log in again.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207786/stop-password-prompt-on-mamp-startup) here at Stack Overflow, but no answer there made me satisfied and the post itself is a bit outdated and hence some of links there are already gone, let me post the question again.

One, I don't like to change permissions of my `/tmp` and its subdirectories to  `a+w`, as suggested in one of the answers on the above link.

Second, I have no knowledge in creating AppleScript and don't like the idea of devoting large amount of time to just solve the issue here. Also, it looks like I have to type in my password in plain text there, which I hope to eschew if I can.

Three, I don't like to use the third-party application if it involves huge security caution and is NOT provided within Mac App Store, which it is in this case.

So are there any other solutions to this issue? Or if I download MySQL directly (I mean, not using MAMP), can I set it such that it doesn't force me to type in password whenever I log in?

For your information, I downloaded MySQL and MongoDB in Ubuntu a few months ago, and I was quite fascinated to see daemons already running without any explicit actions by users whenever I restart and log in to the system. Can I achieve the same in OS X too? That is exactly what I'm longing for...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one month passed, I finally got my solution [from this link](http://stringfoo.com/2008/08/25/tutorial-launching-mamp-silently-on-startup/) - use `plist` to make it automatically start when I log in to the system.